# Unable to change #markup

Tags: views, theming

I'm using Drupal 8, and I want to change the markup of `more_links` from `<a href="/node">more</a>` to something like `<a class="some class" href="/node">more</a>`. I have tried with `mytheme_preprocess_container(&$vars)` with the help of `kint` debug to analysis the `$vars` array. `$vars['element']['#markup']` returns `<a href="/node">more</a>`. However, setting it to a value does not applied.

```
function saidbakr_preprocess_container(&$vars){
 $vars['element']['#markup'] = 'HHHHHHHH';
}
```

I tried to use the `#children` but it has a protected property of markup and I don't know to how use the `create` method?

```
$vars['element']['#children']->create('HHHHH')
```

What's the problem here?

[image]

### Update:

I just have gotten a semi solution, I regard it *semi* because it depends on a direct `echo` from `template_preprocess_container` like the follwoing:

```
function saidbakr_preprocess_container(&$vars){
  $elem = $vars['element'];  
  if ($elem['#type'] == 'more_link'){
    $vars['children'] ='';
    echo str_replace('<a','<a class="btn btn-primary" ', $vars['element']['#children']);
  }
}
```

I used `echo` because setting HTML tags string to `$vars['children']` leads them to be printed as entities on the page. i.e you see the HTML tag of the link instead of the actual link. Is there any concerns about using direct `echo` from the preprocess functions?

Comment: is it a view or a node ??

Comment: It is a view and the meant markup is printed from variable named `{{ more }}` in a template named `views-view.html.twig`.

Comment: Could you show me the full kint output of the elements ?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to change the more variable in template_preprocess_views_view, like:

```
function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  $variables['more'] = \Drupal\Core\Render\Markup::create('<a href="#">HHH</a>');
}
```

Comment: Very good, but there is a little problem remaining. I would like to get the markup of the element `more` i.e `<a href="what ever">more</a>` in order to apply string replace on it before passing it to the `create()` method or at least to have the value of `what ever` for the URL that link points to.

Comment: so - alter the existing render array markup string, `$vars['variables']['#markup']`, or extract the href="XX" out of it

Comment: It's invalid key. However, your solution is the best. It will ultimate one, when we could able to find a way to get the URL or the markup of more link.

Comment: yes sorry - it's `$vars['more']['#markup']`

Comment: Also it is invalid index.

Comment: hmm -- so debug this 'variable', you'll find it .. maybe it's an url object ..

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear, where you are. The template `container` has `children` as output, not `element`. Also in `views-view` there is no `element`. If you change variables, that are not used in the twig, then this will do nothing. Look in the comments at the top of the twig to see what you can change.

But to answer the question. `create()` is a static function and it is used when you create a new Markup object:

```
$vars['abc'] = \Drupal\Core\Render\Markup::create('abc');
```

I don't think Markup has a property or method to change it. You replace the old object with a new one.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you can change the url as well as text of the read more but you will have to implement **template_preprocess_links()**

Below is code snippet to achieve what you are looking for :

> use Drupal\Core\Url;

```
 function mytheme_preprocess_links(&$variables) {
      // some logic enclosing this block
       $variables['links']['node-readmore']['link']['#title'] = t('Custom text ');
$variables['links']['node-readmore']['link']['#url'] = Url::fromUri('base:' . 'node');
$variables['node']['#links']['node-readmore']['#attributes']['class'][]
= 'btn btn-primary';

    }
```

Comment: This was similar to my answer which I deleted after I realised it's not a read-more link, its a "more" link - i.e. what you get from Views.

Comment: Here I don't meant by node read more. Also, in the case of using `preprocess_link` how could we restrict the action only on the `view` more link.